# Complete intersection of a quadric and a cubic in $\Bbb{P}^4$ is a K3 surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, k3-surfaces

I'm familiar with the fact that a smooth quartic $X=Z(F)\subset\Bbb{P}^3$ is a K3 surface. The condition that $K_X\sim 0$ can be shown directly by the adjunction formula, and $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=0$ follows from a general result (which I'm also familiar with), namely:

> If $X\subset \Bbb{P}^n$ is a complete intersection of dimension $d$, then $H^i(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=0$ for all $i=1,...,d-1$.

Now I'm trying to verify that a smooth complete intersection of a quadric and a cubic $Z(F),Z(G)\subset \Bbb{P}^4$ is also a K3 surface.

From the result above, $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=0$ follows immediately. But how do I compute $K_X$ here?

I imagine the adujnction formula could be useful, by I don't know how.

Comment: It is not a K3 surface, it is a quartic del Pezzo surface.

Comment: @Sasha, I'm sorry, I've just corrected it, I should have written "complete intersection of a quadric and a cubic"

Comment: The canonical class can be computed by the adjuction formula again: if $X \subset Y$ is a smooth complete intersection of divisors $D_1,\dots,D_r$ then $K_X = (K_Y + D_1 + \dots + D_r)\vert_X$.

Comment: I only knew the formula for $r=1$. Where can I find a proof for the general case you're mentioning?

Comment: You can prove it yourself (use induction on $r$).

Comment: @Sasha, thank you, I'll try to prove it myself.

Comment: @Sasha, one more thing. Suppose I used the inverse argument: if $X$ is K3 and is the complete intersection of divisors $D_1, D_2\subset\Bbb{P}^4$ with degrees $d_1,d_2$, then $K_X=(K_{\Bbb{P}^4}+D_1+D_2)\big|_X=(-5+d_1+d_2)H\big|_X$, and because $K_X\equiv 0$ we must have $d_1+d_2=5$. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.